# Short quiz about Myhill-Nerode theorem

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, automata, finite-automata

Given is DFA M:

[image]

[image]

1.) `abb` and `bbb`

2.) `baa` and `ab`

3.) `a` and `ε` (where `ε` is the empty word)

4.) `abb` and `baa`

If I understood correctly, `x` and `y` are equivalent to each other (in terms of Nerode), if you add the same suffix for both such that they can be read by the DFA, e.g. they are in `L(M)`

Thus 1.) is false because `abb` throws us into the "endless" state `5`, there is no escape and thus no suffix.

2.) Is true, simply add suffix `aa` and both words will still be accepted.

3.) True, take `a` as suffix.

4.) False, same reason as 1.) you get into the endless state and there is no escape, thus no suffix.

---

Can you confirm if this is correct? Or did I understand the entire concept wrong? :o

Comment: Your question already includes a complete answer to the original problem but no question *about* this answer. Thus, only "yes/no" answers may remain, helping neither you nor future visitors. Please read related meta discussions [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/597/) and [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/519/) and adjust your question accordingly, e.g. by formulating a specific question about a single element of your answer you are uncertain about. If you just want general feedback, you are welcome to visit us in [chat].

Comment: I'm voting to close this as off-topic because it is a request for grading, not a question.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Even without a full grading one can capture a misunderstanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mistaken. Strings $x$ and $y$ are equivalent modulo the language $L$ iff for  **all** suffixes added to the words the results are both in or both outside of the language:

$x\sim_L y$ iff $xw\in L \iff yw\in L$ for every $w$.

In particular, when the strings $x$ and $y$ end in the same state for the (deterministic) automaton $M$, then $x\sim_{L(M)} y$, as they can be extended by exactly the same strings. This also holds for the dead-end state where no strings can extend the original string to acceptance.

Comment: Thank you very much for keeping my question alive and helping! Understood :)